# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una consulta y que me aparezcan datos en 0 en mysql?

Tags: mysql

Necesito hacer una consulta en donde se vean los pesos de los productores en un rango de embarques y si no tiene pesos que aparezca en 0 pero que siempre se muestren los embarque, en esta consulta que pongo a continuación no se muestra el embarque 78 porque no tiene datos pero quiero que aparezcan los datos del productor y peso en 0

```
SELECT embarque.id as idE
       ,fruta.id_productores
       ,concat( productores.nombre, ' ', productores.Ap_p) as nombre
       ,ifnull(round( fruta.peso_kg,2),0) as peso 
  FROM fruta 
 INNER JOIN productores ON fruta.id_productores=productores.id 
 RIGHT JOIN embarque ON fruta.id_embarque=embarque.id 
 WHERE fruta.id_embarque BETWEEN 77 and 79 
   AND fruta.id_productores in (1,2,3) 
 ORDER BY fruta.id_embarque, fruta.id_productores
```

Acá muestro la relación de las tablas que utilicé y lo que me arrojó la consulta que hice...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: He modificado la consulta, mira si ahora funciona. Si quieres que salgan todos los `embarques` yo pondría esa tabla como principal y unidas con `LEFT JOIN` las que puedan no tener elementos.

Answer (score 0):

Para el valor *null* la función idónea es [COALESCE](https://www.w3schools.com/Sql/func_mysql_coalesce.asp) que lo que hace es exactamente obviar los valores nulos y acepta tantos parámetros como necesites, usando el último como valor si todos los demás son *null*

```
SELECT embarque.id as idE
       ,fruta.id_productores
       ,CONCAT( productores.nombre, ' ', productores.Ap_p) as nombre
       ,COALESCE(fruta.peso_kg,0) as peso 
  FROM embarque
  LEFT JOIN fruta ON fruta.id_embarque=embarque.id 
  LEFT JOIN productores ON fruta.id_productores=productores.id 
 WHERE fruta.id_embarque BETWEEN 77 and 79 
   AND fruta.id_productores in (1,2,3) 
 ORDER BY fruta.id_embarque, fruta.id_productores
```

Comment: Aún así sigue sin aparecerme amigo :( .... gracias por comentar